# Atualizar tabela dinâmica com conexão a uma Stored Procedure usando Macro VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Tenho como objetivo trazer os dados de uma Stored Procedure para uma planilha no Excel. Essa Stored Procedure está utilizando dois parâmetros para a consulta.

Excel 2013

SQL Server

### O que eu tenho

Eu montei uma macro que faz a consulta ao banco de dados, atualiza uma tabela com o resultado da consulta (Dados) e depois atualiza a tabela dinâmica (ViewHistorico). Segue o código:

```
Sub Atualizar()
 Dim lDataIni As String
 Dim lDataFim As String
'Obtem os dados do parêmetro para consulta
 lDataIni = "'" & Format(Sheets("ViewHistorico").Range("C1").Value, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SS") & "'"
 lDataFim = "'" & Format(Sheets("ViewHistorico").Range("C2").Value, "yyyyMMdd 23:59:59") & "'"

    Sheets("Dados").Select
    'executa a consulta na planilha Dados para popular a tabela
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from dbDW").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False 'False para forçar a espera da atualização do PowerPivot
        .CommandText = Array("EXEC SpHistoricoCobrancaProdutor " & lDataIni & " , " & lDataFim)
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=dbDW;UID=efritsch;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=C3" _
        ), Array("1089;DATABASE=DW;"))
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from dbDW")
        .Name = "Query from dbDW"
        .Description = ""
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Atualiza o PowerPivot com base na planilha Dados que foi atualizadas
    Sheets("ViewHistorico").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

    MsgBox ("Atualizado com sucesso!")

End Sub
```

### O que eu quero

Gostaria de ao criar um botão da macro eu possa atualizar automaticamente a minha tabela dinâmica sem a necessidade de ter outra tabela. 
Nesse ponto que eu não estou conseguindo, não estou conseguindo desenvolver um código VBA que possibilite atualizar apenas a tabela dinâmica com os dados da consulta da Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de atualizar uma tabela com a conexão à base de dados, utiliza a referência [Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-2017) e atualiza a tabela dinâmica diretamente.

Pequeno exemplo de código genérico sem verificação de erros:

```
Private Sub Macro()
  With New ADODB.Connection
    .Open "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server"
    With .Execute("SELECT * FROM NomeTabela LIMIT 5")
      For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value2 = .Fields.Item(i).Name
      Next
      Dim Linha As Long: Linha = 1
      While Not .EOF
        Linha = Linha + 1
        For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
          Cells(Linha, i + 1).Value2 = .Fields.Item(i)
        Next
        .MoveNext
      Wend
    End With
    .Close
  End With
End Sub
```